# Format exponential number in table header with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to replace the header 'number' by a custom header made in html.
I use vuetify for display data table.

actually I have :

```
                headers: [
                    {text: 'number', value: 'number'},
                    {text: 'car', value: 'car'},
                    {text: 'Total ', value: 'total'},
                    {text: 'Actions', value: 'actions'}
                ],
```

I think, I must play with the template and slot but I'm totaly lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<template v-slot:header.number>
   Here My custom header
</template>
```

that's works great !